# Stop toggle reader view reading "backslash" outloud?

Tags: browser

toggle reader view is reading \ as "backslash" and some documents I've been auditing have hundreds of them. Is there a way to have it not read the ?

For example, a dialog like:
*/"Hello, Susan."/
/"Good Afternoon, Dave"/*

sounds like this:
*Backslash Hello Susan Backslash Backslash Good Afternoon Dave Backslash*

it's not reading . as "period" or , as "comma" or ? as "question mark" but its reading \ out loud.

I tried saving and deleting the backslashes manually, but by my calculations this will take hundreds of hours stretched over thousands of documents.